# Problem modifying a dxGrdid in subclass form

Tags: c#, grid, resize, devexpress

I made a form class in c# that has a devexpress grid, a label and a button, all of them are declared as protected. I created a subclass of that form but, when I try to move or resize the controls, the grid is locked (only the grid, not the other controls).

I checked the locked property, but it's set on false

Any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a problem between Visual Studio 2008 and DevExpress. You can read the solution on this article:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A2912.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I tried out that scenario with DevExpress 9.2 and I had no problem moving the grid.

Thats what i did:

```
   class FormSubClass : Form1
   {
      public FormSubClass()
      {
         this.simpleButton1.Click += new EventHandler(simpleButton1_Click);
      }

      void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         this.gridControl1.Location = new Point(gridControl1.Location.X + 100, gridControl1.Location.Y);
      }
  }
```

You can find my sample app [here](http://www.filedropper.com/dxtestwinforms).